# can not install heroku-container-registry

Tags: heroku, circleci

My circle-ci deployment failed with the following error, this seem an heroku internal server error. 
How can i fix this?

```
set git remote heroku to https://git.heroku.com/repo-name.git
 ▸    heroku-cli: update available from 6.12.9 to 6.13.19-6cd27b3
Installing plugin heroku-container-registry... !
 ▸    yarn --non-interactive --mutex=file:/home/ubuntu/.cache/heroku/yarn
 ▸    --cache-folder=/home/ubuntu/.cache/heroku/yarn exited with code 1
 ▸    error An unexpected error occurred:
 ▸    "http://cli-npm.heroku.com/mimic-fn/-/mimic-fn-1.1.0/e667783d92e89dbd342818b5230b9d62a672ad18/e667783d92e89dbd342818b5230b9d62a672ad18.tgz:
 ▸    Request failed \"500 Internal Server Error\"".
 ▸    


 ▸    heroku-cli: update available from 6.12.9 to 6.13.19-6cd27b3
 ▸    container:push is not a heroku command.
 ▸    Perhaps you meant commands
 ▸    Run heroku help for a list of available commands.
```

also created [an issue in heroku repo](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-container-registry/issues/22)